# SQLAlchemy: Unexpectedly trying to insert data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 models: `Games` and `GamesHealth`. The latter refers to the former with a `ForeignKey`. When I try to insert a `GamesHealth` object with a `game_slug` that already exists in the `Games` table, it still tries to insert something into the `games` table.

Here's the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1048, "Column 'game_name' cannot be null") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO games (game_name, game_slug) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: (None, 'rural-racer')]
```

And here's the minimal full code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import config


Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata


class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'games'

    game_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    game_name = Column(String(70), nullable=False)
    game_slug = Column(String(70), nullable=False, unique=True)


class GamesHealth(Game):
    __tablename__ = 'games_health'

    game_slug = Column(ForeignKey(u'games.game_slug', ondelete=u'CASCADE', onupdate=u'CASCADE'), primary_key=True)


class Database(object):
    def __init__(self):
        db_url = config.DEVELOPMENT_DB_URL
        self.engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=False)
        self.session = Session(self.engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database()
    health = GamesHealth(game_slug='rural-racer')
    db.session.add(health)
    db.session.commit()
```

What am I missing? Is it because `game_slug` in `GamesHealth` is both a foreign key and a primary key?

Comment: yeah but game_name is a column and you need to pass some data, or else make it default to null

Comment: So you say I should pass a `game_name` when creating a `GamesHealth` object? I don't want to insert anything into `games` though? there is already a `Games` object with `game_slug == 'rural-racer'`. I just want to insert an item into `GamesHealth` that refers to it?

Comment: you dont have pass game_name if you make it nullable from the database level, if you dont want to pass name everytime you want to create a gamehealth row

Comment: i realize that, but i don't want anything to be inserted into the games table, so I don't think what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: ok then i have nothing to say bro

Comment: This is because you've inherited `GamesHealth` from `Game`, so SQLAlchemy is trying to do joined table inheritance for you.

Comment: Damn I didn't see that! It was made using `sqlacodegen` and I didn't expect that to come out of it. Thanks so much!